# Top was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, stack, push

So, i seem to have problems with one of my codes for stacks. Apparently, it does not recognize top as one of the parameters of the stack. Please, i do need a lot of help.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int n;
typedef struct {
    int content[100];
    int top;
} stack;
stack mystack;
int pushstack(stack *somestack, int somevalue) {
    if(top+1>=100)
        return 1;
    (*somestack).top++;
    (*somestack).content[(somestack).top]=somevalue;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `somestack->top`?

Answer (score 2):

You have two errors, which must must be changed to:

```
if ((*somestack).top+1>=100)
     ^^^^^^^^^^
```

and

```
(*somestack).content[(*somestack).top]=somevalue;
                      ^
```

Comment: The more common (and some might say easier to read) syntax for `(*a).b` is `a->b`.

Comment: +1 but it would probably be better to use either `(*somestack).` or `somestack->` consistently throughout.

Comment: @PaulR: Consistency is a good goal, but please be consistency with idiomatic use, not some obscure contraption.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting to reference your stack struct's pointer when you are referencing `top` in your `if` statement.  You need to reference top as

```
if((somestack->top)+1>=100)
  return 1;
```

You can also do it as you were doing last half of your code:

```
if((*somestack).top)+1>=100)
  return 1;
```

I personally think the first way is more readable and reduces the clutter in the code.  They do the same thing but I think the `->` notation makes more sense than dereferencing the pointer with `*` and then accessing the structs field with `.`

Don't forget in the second part of to dereference your pointer too

```
(*somestack).content[(*somestack).top]=somevalue;
```

instead of

```
(*somestack).content[(somestack).top]=somevalue;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the earlier answers correcting your code, you might also want to consider making `pushstack` a method of your stack class (this is supposed to be C++, not C, after all):

```
struct stack {
    int content[100];
    int top;

    int push(int somevalue) {
        if (top + 1 >= 100)
            return 1;
        content[top++] = somevalue;
        return 0;
    }
};
```

You might use the class like this:

```
stack mystack;
mystack.push(100);
```

As you can see, this code is a lot cleaner, less verbose and easier to read and understand than the original implementation with a separate function.